# How to generate a math sequence in Bash?

Tags: bash, math, sequence

I am trying to write a piece of code to display something like this:

1

1 51

1 51 101

1 51 101 151

...

```
z1=1

for i in {1..4}
do 
j="$(($i + 1))"
z$j="$((z$i)) $((1 + $((i*50))))"
echo -e "\nz$j"
done
```

However, this is what I end up with:

```
z1=1: command not found
z2=1 51: command not found
z2
z3=0 101: command not found
z3
z4=0 151: command not found
z4
```

z2 is good but none of the following ones are.

If I write `echo -e "\"$((z$j))""`, I end up with 0 for each loop instead of z something.

I cannot find what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to use `let` first, so bash knows you're talking about a mathematical variable and not trying to execute a command.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `seq` to generate a sequence:

```
for i in {1..10} ; do
    seq -s ' ' 1 50 $((1+i*50))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you cannot calculate the variable name in place.

The sh command `myVar=myVal` evaluates the value (right hand side) but does not evaluate the left hand side.  Put your temporary variable name into a variable, then use `${!myVarName}` to extract it.

```
varName="z$i"
${!varName}="whatever"
```

Don't forget to save your oldVarName for use the next time through.

Answer (score 0):

is awk acceptable?

```
kent$  awk -vr=10 'BEGIN{for(i=1;i<=r;i++){s=(i==1)?i:s" "(i-1)*50+1; print s}}'                                                                                            
1
1 51
1 51 101
1 51 101 151
1 51 101 151 201
1 51 101 151 201 251
1 51 101 151 201 251 301
1 51 101 151 201 251 301 351
1 51 101 151 201 251 301 351 401
1 51 101 151 201 251 301 351 401 451
```